# Load a script for the elements of an array

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dynamic form where you can order something.

In basic form, we have one row, but if you want to order more things we can dynamically without reloading the page, add the new row. So far everything is working properly for me, but in this form we have two dropdown ("input select") lists. These drop-down lists are dependent on each other and do not know how to load them the relationship between them and the option of choice. I have tried many different examples from the internet, but always work correctly only the first default row. Dynamically created rows are no longer dependent on one another.

If I am doing something wrong, and you know a better way, please show me this way.

I ask you for help, because I really depend on that. Thank you in advance. ;)

[image: Screenshot of the form]

---

**Update**

Hmm .. Now I understand, but I do not know much how to use it in my web page code. Will show you the web page code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><br>
<html><br>
    <head><br>
        <title>Dynamic forms</title><br>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script><br>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/jquery.validate.js"></script><br>
        <script language="javascript" src="chainedselects.js"></script><br>
        <script language="javascript" src="exampleconfig2.js"></script><br>

    </head>
    <body onload="initListGroup('vehicles', document.formm.elements['group[]'], document.formm.elements['product[]'], 'cs')">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
               var i = 2;
                var templateRow = jQuery.format($("#template").val());
                function addRow() {
                    var ii = i++;
                    $(templateRow(ii)).appendTo("#listProducts tbody");
                    $("#removeProduct_" + ii).click(function(){
                        $("#row_" + ii).remove();
                    });
                }
                $("#addProduct").click(addRow);
            });
        </script>

        <!-- Template row in the table -->

        <textarea id="template" style="display:none;" cols="1" rows="1">
            <tr id="row_{0}" valign="top">
                <td>{0}.</td>
                <td><select name="group[]" style="width: 100%;"></select></td>
                <td><select name="product[]" style="width: 100%;"></select></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="price[]" style="width: 100px;"></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" style="width: 97%;"></td>
                <td><img src="remove.png" id="removeProduct_{0}" alt="remove"></td>
            </tr>
        </textarea>

        <!-- This summary table -->

        <form name="formm" action="parser.php" method="post">
            <table id="listProducts" name="list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nr</th>
                        <th>Group</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                        <th>+/-</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="3" align="left">
                            <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send" style="width: 100px;">
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr valign="top">
                        <td>1.</td>
                        <td><select name="group[]" style="width: 100%;"></select></td>
                        <td><select name="product[]" style="width: 100%;"></select></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="price[]" style="width: 100px;"></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="quantity[]" style="width: 97%;"></td>
                        <td><img src="add.png" id="addProduct" alt="add"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is a parser.php:

```
<?php
$data = array();

$data['Groups'] = $_POST['group'];
$data['Products'] = $_POST['product'];
$data['Prices'] = $_POST['price'];
$data['Quantity'] = $_POST['quantity'];

$result = print_r($data,true);
echo "<pre>$result</pre>";
?>
```

[Here is link to all code](http://www.filesonic.com/file/3899089365/dynamic_form.rar).

Comment: Do I understand this correctly: if a user changes the selection in dropdown1, the options in dropdown2 should change? We'd need a sample of your code to help.

Comment: Yes, you understand. Well, throw the code, but I have to wait until 8 h after addition of questions.

Comment: Although I fixed it for you, please read code formatting rules in editor help. There's really no need to "escape" HTML tags and throw in all `<br/>`s into the code. Just indent with 4 spaces or select full block of code and then press the `{}` code button in editor's toolbar.

Comment: Sorry about that. For the first time I meet with this kind of formatting text. On other forums I've done it differently.

Answer (score 1):

The click events are not attached to the newly created rows, so you need to make sure that any new rows, after they are created have click events attached to them.

```
function dependantFunction() {
   /* code */
}

function addNewRow() {
    var a=document.createElement("div");
    var b=document.createElement("img");
    b.src="images/add.png";
    b.addEventListener("click", dependantFunction, false);   
    a.appendChild(b);
    document.getElementById("rowholder").append(a);
}
```

Then all new rows should have all the necessary events attached to them.

Comment: Beat me to it.. I would say that.

Comment: So, you can help me? Very please with it, because I need it for tomorrow, and probably already tried everything I know.